# how to update prestashop product details from external database?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

i have one grocery shop and i have thinking to sell this product  online .so i used one CMS cart called "prestashop" .

even i have installed and start working on that .but i have some problem.

1. i have my own inventory database to store all product details . with a UI that i can add product details to database (quantity, price etc) . now my question is how can interact with my inventory database using prestashop cart ?

is it possible ? what is the best way to do it ? please help

Comment: You can create a script to import your products/categories/clients to prestashop, you can do it by creating a csv file from your ERP software, you can do the import by webservice also, you should use xml files in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can add the categories from external db using a script in your prestashop site. For this create a module with frontcontroller (for cron job or to run the script) and inside the script select the categories from external db, then loop through the categories and inside the loop create prestashop category object and place the category fields to the category object and call the category save method.

```
public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();
    $temp_categs = array(); //
    //fetch data into $temp_catgs from the external db with the help mysqli_connect or whatever the driver - never modify presta db settings - write php code for db connection to external db and fetch 

    //loop through the fetched categories
    foreach($temp_categs as $categ){
      $new_categ = new Category();

      //set all the field values
      $new_categ->name = $categ['name'];
      $new_categ->id_parent = $categ['id_parent'];
      $new_categ->active = true;
      $new_categ->field2 = $categ['field2'];
      $new_categ->field3 = $categ['field3'];

      //save the category - a category with new id will be created in prestashop
      $new_categ->save();
    }
}
```

}

I hope this would help you.